# Delphi: 3 Tool Buttons - 3 Frames = switching

Tags: delphi, toolbar, frame, switch-statement

I have 3 grouped Tool Buttons (a Tool Bar). One of them is always down. And I have 3 frames. What is the easiest and right way to change the frames switching among the buttons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *right way* is moot at best. One of the easiest ways of many can be to set unique `Tag`s for the grouped buttons, f.i. 0, 1, 2, then set all of the three button's 'OnClick' to the same handler and show one of your frames according to the tag of the clicked button and hide the others:

```
procedure TForm1.ToolButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Frame1.Hide; // will return immediately if already hidden
  Frame2.Hide;
  Frame3.Hide;
  case TToolButton(Sender).Tag of
    0: Frame1.Show;
    1: Frame2.Show;
    2: Frame3.Show;
  end;
end;
```

This is assuming you've already put the frames on your form at design time. Don't forget setting the `Grouped` property of the buttons and their `Style`s to 'tbsCheck'.

Answer (score 1):

If the frames are all in the same position on the screen, then doing it the way the Sertac suggests will make it really cumbersome to see *in the IDE* what they look like on their owner form

I suggest you put the frames in a page control or tab control.

Comment: Dunno, bringing one to front from the structure view is easy for me.. Also, I don't think a tab control would help as it doesn't have pages. Lastly, consider mentioning about the buttons a bit so that this might turn into an actual answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Using the Object Inspector's combo at the top is also an easy way to select controls that may be obscured by others. Besides, frames should not be edited on a form, but on their own. If you need to customize a frame to a specific form, I'd do it in code.